# How can I add custom items to an NSTextField's contextual menu in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, swift, contextmenu

When a user invokes a contextual menu for an NSTextField, Cocoa displays a menu with the usual standard items in it. Can I add my own items to that menu, and if so, how?

I'm using Swift, by the way. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean only within your own app? Or do you want to add contextual menu items to text fields across all apps?

Comment: In my own application for one specific field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to intervene with the field editor that gets used for the text field. Text fields don't directly handle the editing of their contents. They use a text view (instance of `NSTextView` or a subclass) to do that. That text view is called the field editor.

A text view can have a delegate and that delegate can implement the method `-textView:menu:forEvent:atIndex:` to customize the contextual menu. The thing is, when a text view is operating as a field editor, its delegate is always the control that it's acting on behalf of. So, you can't set an arbitrary object of your own (like some window or view controller) to be its delegate.

So, you have to use a custom subclass of `NSTextField` in order to have the opportunity to customize the contextual menu. In your subclass, implement that method and customize the menu that's passed in before returning it (or return a completely different menu if you like).